# react-native while the package is building it gives an error like Unable to resolve module `ReactNativeART

Tags: react-native

Here i am working on react-native. There is no problem while i run "react-native run-android". it builds 100%. But while the packager is building, it gives me an error like "Unable to resolve module `ReactNativeART` from `/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`. i tried watchman clean , npm clean, deleted node_modules and freshly created, but again it shows me the same error. my react-native version is 0.46.4 and react version is 16.0.0-alpha.12. Event i down graded the react and react-native version. But it shows some other errors in ios/pods/react/libraries/ folders. Give me some suggestions please.

Comment: are you using `react-native-firebase` library?

Comment: yes i am using firebase library ("react-native-firebase": "^2.0.0")

Comment: check [this issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/278) there are lots of comments about it. Basically you need to manually link `ReactNativeART` library in your project.

Comment: because of firebase did i got that error?

Comment: oh Thanks i will try it out

Comment: The link you given has discussed about, the ART linking in pod file, i got this error in android. in android where i have to link this ReactNativeART

Comment: You need to manually link the library. I didn't do it myself before so I don't really know how and there is not much documentation about it. There might be another library that uses it in your project. Check their documentations and issues if there are any information about it.

Comment: i fixed that issue by downgrading the react-native version from 0.46.0 to 0.44.1 and react version from 16.0.0-alpha.12 to 16.0.0-alpha.6

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions